# Use GPars to dispatch an async task and return immediately

Tags: asynchronous, groovy, gpars

I would like to have a method that dispatches an async task, and returns immediately. I don't need wait for the result.
I'd like something like this to work:

```
/**
* runs a job and return job id for later montoring.
*/
def int runJob(){
  int jobId = createJob() // returns immediately
  task{
    doSomthingThatTakesSomeTime()
  }.then {stepResult-> doSmtgElse(stepResult)}
  return jobId
}
```

In the situation above, the task won't run, as there's no call for .get()
, however, if I DO .get() , the method will not return jobId until task is finished.

How can i dispatch the task and still return immediately?

Comment: "In the situation above, the task won't run, as there's no call for .get()": it's not true. `task(..)` create a task (Runnable) and call `pool.execute` with this task (which is obviously executed - the threading model depends on the implementation of the pool you use).

Comment: Thanks for you comment, based on it and @pczeus's answer I got something which worked well, i will add it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading @pczeus answer and  Jérémie B's comment I came up with this:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflow.task

def int longTask(){
    def counter = 0
    10.times {
        println "longTask_${counter}"
        counter++
        sleep 10
    }
    counter
}

def int getSomeString() {
    def jobId=55
    task {
        longTask()

    }.then { num -> println "completed running ${num} times" }
    return  jobId
}
println getSomeString()

sleep 2000
```

This prints:

```
longTask_0
55
longTask_1
longTask_2
longTask_3
longTask_4
longTask_5
longTask_6
longTask_7
longTask_8
longTask_9
completed running 10 times
```

Which is what I intended:
the longTask() is running in the background, the getSomeString() retruns without waiting for the long task, and as long as the program is still running (hence the sleep 2000), even the clause in the 'then' part is executed

Comment: Does that mean you got what you wanted out of it?

Comment: I like the code..very 'groovy'. Love Groovy even more!

Answer (score 1):

You can run this example as a Groovy script:

```
    @Grapes(
        @Grab(group='org.codehaus.gpars', module='gpars', version='1.2.1')
    )

    import java.util.concurrent.*
    import groovyx.gpars.*

    def doSomethingThatTakesSomeTime(){
        println "calculating..."
        for(long i: 0..100){
            Thread.sleep(i)
        }

        println "*done*"
        "Done with doSomethingThatTakesSomeTime"
    }

    def doSomethingElse(){
        for(int x:0..1000) print "."
        println "doSomethingElse done."
    }


    /**
    * runs a job and return job id for later montoring.
    */
    def runJob(){
        GParsPool.withPool(){
            Future future = createJob() // returns immediately
            doSomethingElse() //Do someting else while the async process is running
            //Ok, thats done, but the longer runningprocess is still running, return the future
            future
        }
    }

    Future createJob(){
        //create a new closure, which starts the original closure on a thread pool
        Closure asyncFunction = { doSomethingThatTakesSomeTime() }.async()

        //Invoke the function, return a Future
        asyncFunction()
    }

    def job = runJob()
    //println "\n\nResult is: " + job.get()
```

If you run the script "as-is", you will see that it runs and the long running job does print `*done*` indicating it did in fact run to completion, even though the line at the bottom that calls `Future.get()` is commented out and never called.

If you uncomment the last line, you will see the result printed once complete as a result of calling `Future.get()`